# Kali Linux USB Boot Problems

Tags: kali-linux

I have just downloaded Kali Linux and used UNetBootin to install it to a 4GB Sandisk Cruzer. I stuck it in my machine and booted from it. Options come up for:

```
Default
Back
Live (forensic mode)
Install with speech synthesis
Hardware Detection Tool (HDT)
```

However, I can't boot into any of these; they all throw the same error:

```
Segmentation fault at address 0xb7200000

Fatal server error:
Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault). Server aborting.


Please consult The X.Org Foundation support 
                 at http://wiki.x.org
for help
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.

(debconf:4384): Gtk-WARNING ##: Cannot open display: 0
```

There was also a small option graph with 5 options numbers 0-4 headed with the title "Backtrace" but I couldn't read all of the info in it.

Why do I get this error, and how can I work around it?

Comment: are you sure your download isn't corrupted?

Comment: @Happy Yellow Face I don't know how to check, but yes im pretty sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend running a RAM test (try Memtest86+) on the failing machine to ensure the RAM is in good working order. Segmentation faults are usually caused by hardware issues (assuming the software itself is well-tested and doesn't segfault on most hardware).

Answer (score 2):

Do not use UNETBOOTIN, use Win32 Disk Imager if you are using Windows, or dd if you are using linux like so, after verifying the path of the USB storage:

```
dd if=kali.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=512k
```

source, official kali website:
http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-live-usb-install

Answer (score 1):

The problem, and it is the same issue I'm running into, is that UNetbootin creates an invalid `syslinux.cfg` file and the `dd` command creates an invalid drive format (ISO9006 I believe).

syslinux.cfg contains a few mistakes:

```
label ubnentry1
menu label ^Live (forensic mode)
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali noswap noautomount
```

should be

```
label ubnentry1
menu label ^Live (forensic mode)
kernel /live/vmlinuz
append initrd=/live/initrd.img boot=live noconfig=sudo username=root hostname=kali noswap noautomount
```

Also, this:

```
label ubnentry2
menu label ^Graphical install
kernel /ubnkern
append initrd=/install/initrd.gz video=vesa:ywrap,mtrr vga=788 -- quiet
```

should be:

```
label ubnentry2
menu label ^Graphical install
kernel /install/gtk/vmlinuz
append initrd=/install/gtk/initrd.gz video=vesa:ywrap,mtrr vga=788 -- quiet
```

Finally, add:

```
label ubnentry4
menu label ^Text install
kernel /install/vmlinuz
append initrd=/install/initrd.gz vga=788 -- quiet
```

These are the changes needed for Unetbootin to boot.  On the flip side I keep getting an error about needing to install the kernel first.

Answer (score 0):

**Verify Download**

To verify your download, go to http://www.kali.org/downloads/ and find the sha1 hash.

Run the following Linux/Mac command on the file downloaded form kali.org , and see if the numbers match:

```
$ shasum ~/Downloads/kali.tgz   
68b91a8894709cc132ab7cd9eca57513e1ce478b
```

**Display Driver is crashing**

The error messages you have provided, show that the OS is crashing on a Display driver.

You didn't state if you are dual booting Kali linux, or if you are attempting to run it inside a virtual machine. Here are some suggestions.

If you are installing to your actual machine, then you may have an incompatible graphics card. The only solutions would be:

- Wait until an update that includes a patched video driver. Your crash appears to be similar to [this one](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=649346)
- Download the updated graphics card driver, and compile your own OS (not for the faint of heart)
- Disable any additional video cards in your bios (tv tuners, ect...)

**Alternatives**

While not a *fix*, I would recomend running kali linux inside a Virtual Machine. Kali is a dedicated OS, and should not be used for your primary work. You can download a VM that is already to go from Kali.org. Just select 'VmMare' from the 'image type' drop down box.

Comment: I clearly stated that I was using a 4GB Sandisk Cruzer to boot. @spuder

Comment: Yep, overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to format the USB and then use this command:

```
dd if=/fali-linux/kali-linux.iso of=/dev/sdb
```

Answer (score 0):

I used rufus (http://rufus.akeo.ie/) to create my bootable USB drive when installing Kali Linux. Perhaps give that a try?